# Why are functions returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am working with a form and using functions to create returns which will then be used for a total calculation at the end of the form.

There are two functions which are returning `undefined` and I haven't been able to figure out why. I believe I am accessing the form elements properly. I have checked the array keys using console log and get valid numbers.

Any help would be great. I am including HTML & external script.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>    
    <title>Square Foot Form</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="sqfoot_script.js"></script>
    <link href="sqfoot_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
        <form action="" id="sqfoot" onsubmit="return false;">
        <div>
            <div class="cont_order">
               <fieldset>
                <legend>Calculate Your Rental Rate</legend>
                <label> How many plants do you want to grow ? </label>
                <select size="1" <select id="plantNumber" name="plantNumber" onchange="getNumberOfPlants();">
                <option value="None">Select number of plants</option>
                <option value="1"> 1</option>
                <option value="2"> 2</option>
                <option value="3"> 3</option>
                <option value="4"> 4</option>
                <option value="5"> 5</option>
                <option value="6"> 6</option>
                <option value="7"> 7</option>
                <option value="8"> 8</option>
                <option value="9"> 9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
                <option value="13">13</option>
                <option value="14">14</option>
                <option value="15">15</option>
                <option value="16">16</option>
                <option value="17">17</option>
                <option value="18">18</option>
                <option value="19">19</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
                <option value="21">21</option>
                <option value="22">22</option>
                <option value="23">23</option>
                <option value="24">24</option>
                <option value="25">25</option>

               </select>
               <br><br/>                
                <label> What size plants are you starting with ? </label>

                <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="plantType" value="16" onclick="getSquareInches(); calculateSquareFeet();" />Seeds, havn't started yet</label><br/>
                <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="plantType" value="16" onclick="getSquareInches(); calculateSquareFeet();" /> Seedlings, less than 2ft high</label><br/>
                <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="plantType" value="64" onclick="getSquareInches(); calculateSquareFeet();" /> Juvenile, 2 - 4ft high</label><br/>
                <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="plantType" value="144" onclick="getSquareInches(); calculateSquareFeet();" /> Adult, 4ft or higher</label><br/>
                <br/>
                <label > Grow Type </label>

                <select id="Grow_Type" name='Grow_Type' onchange="getGrowType();">
                <option value="None">Select Grow Type</option>
                <option value="15">Traditional soil based</option>
                <option value="21">Hydroponic</option>
                <option value="None"> Undecided</option>

               </select>
                <br><br/>
                <label > Choose Set-up </label>

                <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="SetUp" value="our" onclick="areaTimesType(); getSetUp(); calculateTotal();" />Our Grow Set Up</label><br/>
                <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="SetUp" value="your" onclick="areaTimesType(); getSetUp(); calculateTotal();" />Your Grow Set Up</label><br/>


                <div id="totalPrice">
                <!-- <input type="button" id="myButton" name="totalButton" value="Calculate" onclick="claculateTotal();"> -->
                </div>

                </fieldset>
            </div>


       </form>
    </div><!--End of wrap-->

</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var num_plant= new Array();
    num_plant ["none"] = 0;
    num_plant [1] = 1;
    num_plant [2] = 2;
    num_plant [3] = 3;
    num_plant [4] = 4;
    num_plant [5] = 5;
    num_plant [6] = 6;
    num_plant [7] = 7;
    num_plant [8] = 8;
    num_plant [9] = 9;
    num_plant [10] = 10;
    num_plant [11] = 11;
    num_plant [12] = 12;
    num_plant [13] = 13;
    num_plant [14] = 14;
    num_plant [15] = 15;
    num_plant [16] = 16;
    num_plant [17] = 17;
    num_plant [18] = 18;
    num_plant [19] = 19;
    num_plant [20] = 20;
    num_plant [21] = 21;
    num_plant [22] = 22;
    num_plant [23] = 23;
    num_plant [24] = 24;
    num_plant [25] = 25;


 var square_inches = new Array();
    square_inches ["seeds"]=16;
    square_inches ["seedlings"]=16;
    square_inches ["juveniles"]=64;
    square_inches ["adult"]=144;

var type_grow = new Array();
    type_grow ["select"] =0;
    type_grow ["traditional"] =15;
    type_grow ["hydroponic"] =21;
    type_grow ["undecided"] =0;

var set_up = new Array();
    set_up ["our"] =10;
    set_up ["your"] =5;


function getNumberOfPlants()
{
    var userNumberChoice=0;    
    var theForm = document.forms["sqfoot"];    
    var selectedPlantNum = theForm.elements["plantNumber"];    
    userNumberChoice = num_plant[selectedPlantNum.value];    
    return userNumberChoice;    
}

function getSquareInches()
{  
    var thePlantSize=0;    
    var theForm = document.forms["sqfoot"];    
    var selectedPlant = theForm.elements["plantType"];    
    for(var i = 0; i < selectedPlant.length; i++)
    {        
        if(selectedPlant[i].checked)
        {           
            thePlantSize = square_inches[selectedPlant[i].value];            
            break;
        }
    }    
    return thePlantSize;
}

function calculateSquareFeet()
{   
    return (getNumberOfPlants() * getSquareInches()) / 144;     
}

function getGrowType()
{
    var userGrowChoice=0;    
    var theForm = document.forms["sqfoot"];    
    var selectedGrowType = theForm.elements["Grow_Type"];    
    userGrowChoice = type_grow[selectedGrowType.value];    
    return userGrowChoice;
}

function areaTimesType()
{
    return calculateSquareFeet() * getGrowType();
}

function getSetUp()
{  
    var theSetUpChoice=0;    
    var theForm = document.forms["sqfoot"];    
    var selectedSetUp = theForm.elements["SetUp"];    
    for(var j = 0; j < selectedSetUp.length; j++)
    {        
        if(selectedSetUp[j].checked)
        {            
            theSetUpChoice = set_up[selectedSetUp[j].value];            
            break;
        }
    }    
    return theSetUpChoice;
}

function calculateTotal()
{    
    var theWholeThing = areaTimesType() + getSetUp();     
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "Total Price For grow space $"+theWholeThing;
}
```

Comment: Give us a hint: which function(s) are returning `undefined`?

Comment: you have an html error which I guess causing your problems: `<select size="1" <select id="plantNumber" name="plantNumber" onchange="getNumberOfPlants();">`

Comment: is your javascript code wrapped in `<script>` tags?

Comment: Sorry I just realized I didn't state which two functions I was referring to. They are getSquareInches and getGrowType.

Comment: Agreed -- that's a lot of code to read through. Try to limit your code samples to the minimum needed to troubleshoot the issue. People are unlikely to scroll through all the code you've posted here. You've posted nearly 200 lines here.

Comment: Thought all of it was needed to see where possible flaw is.

Comment: What is my HTML error?

Comment: your html error in <select size="1" then with out continuing this select or anything you're opening another select <select id="plantNumber".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured out your issue, is that in your drop downs, and radio buttons you're sending the actual numbers to the array not the actual word, while your defined arrays are based on the words

i.e.

```
square_inches ["seeds"]=16;
```

but in your function you were asking for

```
square_inches [16]
```

so you're getting undefined. All you have to do is change the values of the radio buttons and the drop down of grow type

here's a working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/7mn5a/1/

here's a fiddle with alerts of your values when you choose a radio button or change the grow type drop down

http://jsfiddle.net/7mn5a/2/

Comment: Many thanks for solving this. Many hours trying to determine problem.